# Skinny-ORMでコンストラクタ引数とテーブルのカラム名が一致しない場合の定義の仕方を教えてください。

Tags: scala, playframework, scalikejdbc

以下の様なテーブルとクラスがあるとします。

sql

```
create table `sample`.`member` (id serial, name varchar(64));
```

class

```
case class Member(id: Long, hoge: String)
```

Memberテーブルのnameカラムを、Memberクラスのhogeにマッピングしたいと思っているのですが方法はありますか？

試した実装は以下です。

```
package domain.models

import scalikejdbc.WrappedResultSet
import scalikejdbc.ResultName
import skinny.orm.SkinnyMapper


case class Member(id: Long, hoge: String)

object Member extends SkinnyMapper[Member] {
  override lazy val defaultAlias = createAlias("m")
  override def extract(rs: WrappedResultSet, n: ResultName[Member]): Member = {
    new Member(
      id = rs.get(n.id),
      hoge = rs.get(n.name)
    )
  }
}
```

この様な実装をし、以下を実行しました。

```
Member.findById(1)
```

すると、

```
domain.models.Member#name not found. Expected fields are #id, #hoge.
```

というエラーがでます。

Answer (score 1):

DBのカラム名とモデルのプロパティ名が違う時はこの変数をオーバーライドしてあげると変換できます。

```
override val nameConverters = Map("hoge" -> "name")
```

Map("モデルのカラム名" -> "DBのカラム名")

```
package domain.models

import scalikejdbc.WrappedResultSet
import scalikejdbc.ResultName
import skinny.orm.SkinnyMapper


case class Member(id: Long, hoge: Option[String])

object Member extends SkinnyMapper[Member] {
  override lazy val defaultAlias = createAlias("m")
  override val nameConverters = Map("hoge" -> "name")
  override def extract(rs: WrappedResultSet, n: ResultName[Member]): Member = {
    new Member(
      id = rs.get(n.id),
      hoge = Some(rs.get(n.hoge))
    )
  }
}
```